# How to rotate a node and text independently in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, rotating

How can I rotate the `text` inside a `node` independent of the `node` in `tikz`? Right now I am using the `rotatebox`. The other option I tried was to have two overlapping nodes.
Is there a better way to do this?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}   % For trapezium
\usepackage{rotating}                   % For rotatebox
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% Text orientation is wrong
\node[draw, trapezium, rotate=-90, minimum height=1.2cm, trapezium stretches body] at (1,1.5) {Component};
% Method 1 using rotatebox
\node[draw, trapezium, rotate=-90, minimum height=1.2cm, trapezium stretches body] at (3,1.5) {\rotatebox{180}{Component}};
% Method 2 overlapping nodes
\node[draw, trapezium, rotate=-90, minimum height=1.2cm, trapezium stretches body, text=white] at (5,1.5) {Component};
\node[trapezium, rotate=90, minimum height=1.2cm, trapezium stretches body] at (5,1.5) {Component};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Getting text orientation right]

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use `shape border rotate=<anbgle>` to rotate the shape.  The combination  `rotate=90, shape border rotate=180` produces the shape and text rotated in the desired direction (as in first image):

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}   % For trapezium 
\usepackage{rotating}               % For rotatebox

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% Text orientation is wrong
\node[draw, trapezium, rotate=90, minimum height=1.2cm, trapezium stretches body, shape border rotate=180] at (1,1.5)  {Component};
% Method 1 using rotatebox
\node[draw, trapezium, rotate=-90, minimum height=1.2cm, trapezium stretches body] at (3,1.5) {\rotatebox{180}{Component}};
% Method 2 overlapping nodes
\node[draw, trapezium, rotate=-90, minimum height=1.2cm, trapezium stretches body, text=white] at (5,1.5) {Component};
\node[trapezium, rotate=90, minimum height=1.2cm, trapezium stretches body] at (5,1.5) {Component};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It works without `decorate` too. Any reason to include `\usetikzlibrary{decorations}`?

Comment: @mythealias: Was left over from an earlier attempt at a fix. Have updated solution to removed it.

Comment: With the current version `shape border rotate=-X` does not seem to work, use `shape border rotate=Y` with Y=360-X instead.

Comment: `shape border rotate` does not work for all symbols.