# How we can design our own boxed titles?

Tags: framed, tcolorbox, frame-title

```
\begin{tcolorbox}
  \centering
  I am a fool..\\ I dont know How to make this box small as text has. 
\end{tcolorbox}
```

I am using the above code to create boxed titles in my notes..
My output is

[image]

### Question:

1. How to give color this box?
2. How to make short as much as to the text width last?
3. Can I have like the following?
   [image]

Comment: Three questions in one!

Comment: for the pretty shapes, see, for example, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151962/rotating-a-custom-shape-independently-of-the-text

Answer (score 3):

Use `\tcbox` or `\newtcbox` to use a box or defining a new one which is just as wide as needed (apart from settings concerning special settings)

The background colour can be specified with `colback=some color`.

For the boxed title use -- well `attach boxed title to ...` (it's all in the manual ;-) and combine with the various options of `colback` or `borderline` to provide a nicer output. This works for `tcbox` or `\newtcolorbox` as well.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage[x11names,svgnames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{blindtext}


\newtcolorbox{somebox}[2][]{enhanced,colback=white,width={0.5\textwidth},
attach boxed title to top left={yshift={-0.5\baselineskip},xshift=1cm}, 
title={#2},
boxrule=0.5pt,
coltitle=black,
boxed title style={enhanced,
  borderline={0.5mm}{-0.5mm}{LightGreen,solid},
  colframe=white,
  colback=LightGreen,
  colupper={black},
},
borderline={0.5mm}{-1mm}{LightGreen,solid},#1%
}


\begin{document}

\tcbox[colback=lightgray]{This box is just as wide as needed}


\tcbox[colback=LightGreen]{This box is just as wide as needed}



\begin{somebox}{Hello World}
\blindtext
\end{somebox}



\end{document}
```

[image]